# show information in column depending on whether it is an adult or a child SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my SQL database:

Table 1: `Person`:

| Application | NoPerson | Name | Lastname | Salary | DateofBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | name1 | lastname1 | 2000 | 1990-03-03 |
| 01 | 02 | name2 | lastname2 | NULL | 2010-01-01 |
| 02 | 01 | name1 | lastname1 | 2000 | 1993-03-03 |
| 02 | 02 | name2 | lastname2 | NULL | 2012-01-01 |

Table 2 : `EducationInfo`:

| Application | NoPerson | schoolgrade | school | goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 02 | 8. grade | St. Luis | Be Engineer |
| 02 | 02 | 3. grade | norcross | Be Professor |

I need to make a query that returns something like this: If the person is an adult, then show in column occupation his salary. And if it is a child, then show in same column the school grade.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result - a [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: is in sql server

Comment: Generally speaking, the attribute "salary" will be numeric while "8.grade" is a string. A column is a single, specific datatype. If you intend to pursue this approach, you will need to decide what datatype to use and the associated values you intend to include in that datatype. But how exactly do you know any given person is an "adult"? I don't see an obvious way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use something like this:

```
select ...., coalesce(p.Salary, e.schoolgrade) as ocupation
from Person p
left join EducationInfo e on e.Aplication=p.Aplication and e.NoPerson=p.NoPerson
```

We join two tables and then show in `ocupation` column value `Salary` or `schoolgrade` depending on `Salary` is `null` or not.

Answer (score 0):

thaks for help, i does this finally

```
Select *,
CASE WHEN
(P.Salary=0)THEN e.schoolgrade
ELSE CAST(p.Salary AS VARCHAR)
END AS Ocupation
FROM v_APP_Person AS P
LEFT JOIN v_APP_Education  AS e ON p.Aplication= e.Aplication and p.NoPerson=e.NoPerson
```